# Webservice Renders SSRS Report Connection failure

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, reporting-services

I am pulling my hair out. I have taken over a project where existing code is like this:

```
'Try
        Dim rs As New webreportexecution2005.ReportExecutionService()

        rs.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("auser", "******", "")
        'rs.Url = "http://companyweb.com/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx"

        ReportName = Replace(ReportName, "BuildingTabStackingFloorSumNewCust7", "BuildingTabStackingFloorSumNewCust3")

        ' Render arguments
        Dim result As Byte() = Nothing
        Dim reportPath As String = "/CompanyFolder/" + ReportName
        Dim format As String = "PDF"
        Dim historyID As String = Nothing
        Dim devInfo As String = "False"

        Dim intNumParams As Integer = 0
        If Not FloorIDs = "" Then

            intNumParams = 1
        End If

        If ReportName.EndsWith("NoBreaks") And FloorIDs = "" Then
            intNumParams = intNumParams + 1
        End If


        Dim param(intNumParams) As webreportexecution2005.ParameterValue
        param(0) = New webreportexecution2005.ParameterValue

        param(0).Name = ParameterName
        param(0).Value = ParameterValue

        'if combined building and floor report, need to add the floor ids
        If Not FloorIDs = "" Then
            param(1) = New webreportexecution2005.ParameterValue

            param(1).Name = "FloorIDs"
            param(1).Value = FloorIDs
        End If

        If ReportName.EndsWith("NoBreaks") And FloorIDs = "" Then
            param(intNumParams) = New webreportexecution2005.ParameterValue

            param(intNumParams).Name = "PropertyName"
            param(intNumParams).Value = Session("PropertyName")

        End If

        Dim credentials As DataSourceCredentials() = Nothing
        Dim showHideToggle As String = Nothing
        Dim encoding As String = ""
        Dim mimeType As String = ""
        Dim warnings As webreportexecution2005.Warning() = Nothing
        Dim reportHistoryParameters As ParameterValue() = Nothing
        Dim streamIDs As String() = Nothing

        Dim execInfo As New webreportexecution2005.ExecutionInfo
        Dim execHeader As New webreportexecution2005.ExecutionHeader()
        Dim SessionId As String
        Dim extension As String = ""

        rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader
        rs.Timeout = 10000000

        execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID)

        rs.SetExecutionParameters(param, "en-us")

        SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID

        result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, extension, _
           encoding, mimeType, warnings, streamIDs)

        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AppendHeader("content-length", result.Length)
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.BinaryWrite(result)
        Response.End()
        Response.Flush()
        Response.Close()
```

On my local machine, things seem to work fine. A pop-up loads and the page generates a PDF report correctly. When I release the code to the server, things don't go very well. Instead, I receive this:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.205.99.209:80


Source Error: 


Line 456:
Line 457:        execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID)
```

I seem to think the problem at hand is some configuration issue so here's the details:

Windows server 2008

MSSQL 2008

SSRS 2008

IIS 7, ASP.Net 4.0

Application Pool 4.0, Integrated, user = NetworkService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess more than anything it is a firewall not allowing the SSRS host to be contacted.  If you are providing credentials explicity and not getting in that could be an issue related to contacting the service itself.  Before diving down into your VB.NET code I would go to the server directly and try to get to:

```
http://companyweb.com/reportserver
```

If you can get there as the default admin then try to use that account in your code (not sure if it is already).  I know I had issues with connecting to code remotely with SSRS in the past as well and it almost always was an issue with a user having permission here, but not there, or part of this but not part of that.  You may also try to host the service on a port other than 80, which is the default as sometimes servers block port 80 by default if they have not specifically been opened up in Windows Firewall.  Then you could go into the server and check the firewalls.

I often explicitly set SSRS to use a port other than 80 as well.